# Invalid operands to binary expression ('char (*)[36]' and 'char *')

Tags: ios, sqlite

```
-(void)setFlagToZero:(BOOL)flg id:(NSString *)qid
{
    NSLog(@"flag %hhd and ID:%@ ",flg,qid);
    sqlite3 *database;
    quiz = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sqlStatement = &"UPDATE  Question set Question_Flag="+flg+"where question_ID="+qid;
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *aQuestion = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error occured in connection");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
@end
```

it is showing error as below

Invalid operands to binary expression ('char (*)[36]' and 'char *')

please help me with the corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the following statement (you have added `&` and `+` in that string):

```
const char *sqlStatement = &"UPDATE  Question set Question_Flag="+flg+"where question_ID="+qid;
```

Change it to:

```
NSString *query          = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE  Question set Question_Flag=%d where question_ID=%d",flg,qid];
const char *sqlStatement = [query UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for update , It's working

```
 -(void)updateDataBaseRecords:(NSString *)databaseQuery
{
    NSString *replaceStatement = databaseQuery;
    // Execute the replace
    char *error;
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, [replaceStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Updated successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
    }

}
```

In this function direct pass your query